# FileReader has also buffered method

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I just found this

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("SomePath");
char[] buf = new char[100];
reader.read(buf);
```

So why should I use BufferedReader if FileReader itself has a method to read more than 1 byte.

Comment: You’re missing the key word: buffered. The more you go to the disk, the more I/O you do. Why do you think caches exist?

Answer (score 1):

Because the 100 character array you passed to the `read(char[])` method is much smaller than the most efficient block size that can be read from the hard drive. The buffer allows you to make reads in sizes that are convenient to your code while still maintaining the optimal read size in the hardware layer.

What's the optimal read size for `BufferedReader` then? It depends on the underlying data source. If you don't know it, use the default size.

Comment: static int defaultCharBufferSize = 8192;    So default size of BufferedReader is 8192 Bytes. So I can also make FileReader buffer of this size. So what is the difference than. FileReader reader = new FileReader("SomePath");
char[] buf = new char[8192];
reader.read(buf);

Comment: Explanation for that was already included in the original answer.